# matlab Band-pass Filter not working

Tags: matlab, filter, signals

I try to simulate a noisy signal and Filter it. the signal mix some low frequency signals and some random noise. my goal is to get 14.8Hz signal.
my band-pass bandwidth is 14.7Hz to 14.9Hz.

```
function filteringTest

Hd = KaiserFilter;


Fs = 4000;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;                     % Sample time
L = 40000;                     % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector


r1 = 320;
r2 = 575;

y = 50*sin(2*pi*14.8*t) + r1*sin(2*pi*14.7*t) +  r2*sin(2*pi*15.1*t) + 10.1*rand(size(t));
yfilter = filter(Hd.Numerator,1,y);
plot(yfilter)



function Hd = KaiserFilter

Fs = 4000;  % Sampling Frequency

N    = 4096;     % Order
Fc1  = 14.7;     % First Cutoff Frequency
Fc2  = 14.9;     % Second Cutoff Frequency
flag = 'scale';  % Sampling Flag
Beta = 0.5;      % Window Parameter
% Create the window vector for the design algorithm.
win = kaiser(N+1, Beta);

% Calculate the coefficients using the FIR1 function.
b  = fir1(N, [Fc1 Fc2]/(Fs/2), 'bandpass', win, flag);
Hd = dfilt.dffir(b);
```

my signal image is :
[image: Original Signal]

and filter result is :
[image: Filtered Signal]

when i try to increase Filter Order from 4096 to 32*4096 , i get this result :
[image: Filtered Signal]

why this filter do not work correct? do i chage my filtering method?
what should i do to get 14.8Hz frequency signal?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is your sampling rate so high? Reduce your sampling rate and use a notch filter to take out a selective frequency. I have re-written some sections of your code:

```
Fs = 200;
desiredFrequency = 14.8;
[b,a] = NotchFilter(Fs, desiredFrequency)
```

In the filter definition, you can do this:

```
function [b,a] = NotchFilter(Fs,desiredFrequency)
w = desiredFrequency/(Fs/2);
[b,a] = iirnotch(w,w/400);
```

Now perform the filtering

```
y_filter = filtfilt(b,a,y);
desiredSignal = y-y_filter;
plot(desiredSignal,'LineWidth',2); hold on; plot(y,'LineWidth',2)
```

You'll see something like this.

[image]